# Import xgboost in anaconda?

Tags: ubuntu, xgboost

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
```

I used the official documention to install xgboost on ubuntu. There were no errors, but when I start up my ipython notebook which is anaconda environment, import xgboost show the error that this is no module.

How to import xgboost in my anaconda python environment?

Should I need to modify some environmental variables in ubuntu?

Comment: You can install xgboost using pip: `pip install xgboost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing is happening for me while using Spyder.
I am able to import it using terminal (with a deprecation warning) i.e:

```
   pinaki@Excalibur:~$ python
   Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> from xgboost import XGBClassifier
   /home/pinaki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
    "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
    >>>
```

But while trying to run the same code using Spyder got the following error:

```
  from xgboost import XGBClassifier
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-9b31cfdb821c>", line 1, in <module>
  from xgboost import XGBClassifier

  File "/media/pinaki/MyStuff/Work/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 10 - Model Selection & Boosting/Section 49 - XGBoost/XGBoost/xgboost.py", line 30, in <module>
  from xgboost import XGBClassifier

  ImportError: cannot import name 'XGBClassifier'
```

and pip install xgboost returned the following output:

```
   Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in /home/pinaki/xgboost/python-package
   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/pinaki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from xgboost)
   Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/pinaki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from xgboost)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use conda command:

conda install -c conda-forge xgboost

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem got fixed by renaming the working file from xgboost.py to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to `python-package` folder inside `xgboost` folder and run `setup.py` as well.

After

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
```

Run

```
cd python-package; sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this *conda* command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Or *pip*:

```
pip install xgboost
```